# Getting error in angular function calling

Tags: angular

I have below function which return an array-based it has two inputs one is type and second one is input array.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai updated my answer please check

Comment: You need to assert the type before you start calling properties. The pipe means the instance can implement `IAssetClass` *or* `ICurrency` so you can't assume that an instance will have field `assetClass` available.

Comment: @Igor  can you help me in this as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329020/how-to-use-set-methods-with-default-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assert the type before you start calling properties. The pipe means the instance can implement `IAssetClass` *or* `ICurrency` so you can't assume that an instance will have field `assetClass` available.

```
  getChartData(type : Type, data : (IAssetClass | ICurrency)[])  : IChartClass[] {
    let returnArr = [];
    if (type === 0) {
      returnArr = data.map(
        (row:IAssetClass) => ({ 'name': row.assetClass, 'weighting': row.weighting }),
      )
    } else {
      returnArr = data.map(
        (row:ICurrency) => ({ 'name': row.riskCurrency, 'weighting': row.weighting }),
      )
    }  
    return returnArr;  
  }
```

Comment: can you help me in this as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329020/how-to-use-set-methods-with-default-functions