# How to use set methods with Input vatiables having defaults value as well?

Tags: angular

In a component I have two input variables

```
@Input() public data: User[] = []
@Input() public type: UserType = 'A1';
```

If the value of above variables change I need to call a function for this I have used below method

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     if (changes.type && changes.data) {              
      this.userList = this.userService.getAllUsersList(changes.type.currentValue, changes.data.currentValue);
     }
  }
```

But I need to change this I need to use Setters function instead of ngOnChanges. Below is my approaches but I am getting error. I have commented direct declaration

```
 //@Input() public data: User[] = [] not using this type declaration
   // @Input() public type: UserType = 'A1'; not using this type declaration

 @Input() set  type(value: UserType) {    

 }  

 @Input() set  data(value: User[] ) {    

 }
```

**Issues I am getting**

1) Not able to define variable type like public when I am doing this I am getting error

```
 @Input() set public type(value: UserType) {    

 }
```

2) Not able to set default value

3) Confused how to call getAllUsersList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `property-watch-decorator` from npm.

```
npm i property-watch-decorator
```

Then use `@OnChange` decorator before `@input`

```
export class TestComponent {

   @OnChange(TestComponent.prototype.userList)
   @Input() type: UserType = 'A1'

   @OnChange(TestComponent.prototype.userList)
   @Input data: User[] = [];


   private userList() {
      if (this.data && this.user.length) {
         this.userService.getAllUsersList(changes.type.currentValue, changes.data.currentValue);
      }
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      // To handle default values.
      this.userList();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private type: UserType = 'A1';
@Input('type') set setType(type: UserType) {    
   this.type = type;
   this.userList();
}  

private data: User[] = [];
@Input('data') set setData(data: User[] ) {    
   this.data = data;
   this.userList();
}


private userList() {
   if (this.data && this.user.length) {
      this.userService.getAllUsersList(changes.type.currentValue, changes.data.currentValue);
   }
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   // If there is no input value, then setter is never called.
   // So we have to call it.
   this.userList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer please suggest my approach is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with the properties you need for the component:

```
class myOptions{
  data: User[] = [];
  type: UserType = 'A1';
}
```

in your TypeScript code use:

```
@Input() public options: myOptions
```

and use it in your HTML code as a single parameter:

```
<my-component ... [options]="myOptions" />
```

That replacement of a simple parameter to a class will allow you to make any settlers you want (and run any code you need) on any property by simply replacing field to a property, like this:

```
class myOptions{
  myValuesHaveChange: Function;
  private _data: User[] = [];
  get data(): User[] { return this._data;};
  set data(value: User[]): void { 
        this._data = value; 
        this.myValuesHaveChange(value)};
  type: UserType = 'A1';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer please suggest my approach is correct or not?

Comment: I think you may not be able to use Input() on a property, that is why I suggest to use an object where you are free to set settlers and subscribe any event you need.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this way please suggest is this is correct approach. As I don't want to add other variables

```
public type: UserType = 'A1';
  @Input('type') set  SetType(value: UserType) {    
    this.type = value;    
    this.userList = this.userService.getAllUsersList(value, this.data);
  }

  @Input() public data: User[] = [];
  @Input('data') set  setData(value: User[]) {  
      this.data = value; 
      this.userList = this.userService.getAllUsersList(this.type, value);
  }
```

Comment: there is 2 problem. 1- there is 2 `@input` for `data`. 2- if parent componen send no value for `type` and `data`, then `userlist` will be undefined

Comment: I khonw another solution, If you want to write fewer code

Comment: @miladfm  yes please share here

Comment: see my new answer